# Is it possible in typescript to define a conditional return type and not use typecasting in the function body?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to correctly set the return type of a function based on the input values, and then typescript forces me to use `as`keyword to solve the problem I'm having.
Is there any way to avoid this and is there an elegant solution?

```
type TestReturnType<T> = T extends string ? number : string;

const test = <T,>(value: T): TestReturnType<T> => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return 1 as TestReturnType<T>; // ?
    } else {
        return '1' as TestReturnType<T>; // ?
    } 
};

const res1 = test('String'); 
const res2 = test(13123);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function overloading to accomplish this:

```js
type TestReturnType<T> = T extends string ? number : string;

function test(value: string): TestReturnType<string>;
function test(value: number): TestReturnType<number>;
function test<T>(value: T): TestReturnType<string | number> {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return '1';
    }
}

const res1 = test('String');   // res1: number
const res2 = test(13123);      // res2: string
```

Note that,

- if you omit the overloads, both `res1` and `res2` will have a type of `string | number`
- you can remove the type parameter of test and declare it as `function test(value: any)`

Answer (score 1):

No, currently when a function returns a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, you need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling "typecasting") in the `return` line, or do something equivalently loosely typed (such as [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the function).  There's no way to get compiler-verified type safety, unfortunately.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the relevant feature request.

The problem is that while [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) can be used to narrow the types of *values* of generic types, it does not affect the generic type *parameter* at all.  Inside your `test()` function, `typeof value === "string"` can narrow `value` from `T` to `T & string`, but `T` itself does not change to be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string`.  Thus the type `T extends string ? number : string` cannot be evaluated as `number`; it's just `T extends string ? number : string`.